# npm console.table logs shows nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, console

I'm running into an odd problem with the node package console.table. I'm trying to return a table from an array and getting nothing, not even an error. I've compared code with friends who seem to be getting it to run fine, but unless there's something terribly wrong with how node runs on my computer I'm guessing it's something i'm not seeing.

I've confirmed that it's actually installed and required and tried running it as the documentation specifies

```
console.table({'this':'that})
```

but when I run it in terminal it pauses and then waits for another command. Anyone else had this problem and have some suggestions?
(sorry if this is a bit of a run on, first time asking)

Comment: I think the problem is because of missing square brackets `[ ]`. Try `console.log([{'this':'that'}])`

Comment: just tried, same issue

Comment: Are you running this in the `node` console? Or in your browser's console?

Comment: I'm running it in the node console, I tried using chromes inspector as well but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

In relatively modern version of node ( 7.something ) console is delegated to V8 so that it's correctly wired to chrome remote debugging protocol agent (aka "inspector"). Some functions that are browser specific currently are no-ops without inspector attached, but if you [attach debugger](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/) you'll see `console.table()` output in debugerr's console

see also:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12675

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1716

Comment: I conformed this behavior